# how to use Promise reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

first experience with react,
the script return a list of Promise.

[image]

how i can update **uploadedImages**  ?

```
const [uploadedImages, setUploadedImages] = useState<CustomImage[]>([]);

...

const fileToImagePromises = liste.map(fileToImageURL);
console.log(fileToImagePromises) // return liste of Promise objet 
Promise.all(fileToImagePromises).then(setUploadedImages);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specific to react, it is JavaScript,

Using the callback as

`Promise.all(fileToImagePromises).then(data => setUploadedImages(data))`

But the point would be where you are setting the state, if you do it unconditionally in function component body it would infinitely re-render

Comment: i see date is <img> but uploadedImages is empty?

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand

Comment: is work when i validate 2 time, i have someting other thank you